# EF4 - Get Child Value

Tags: c#, entity-framework

i'm beginning with EF4,

In my Controller class, i have an object like this

```
House
   ->List<Wall>
           ->List<Windows>
```

Because i want to be able to cancel change, i keep this data in a object

(i use SaveChange to "commit" data)

I would like to have a function like that :'`Windows getWindowsById(Guid IdWindows)`'

Is their any better way to get my windows without iterating with "wall" and "windows" (`foreach ...`) ?

I use CTP5 so maybe a query with the `Local` propertie can be a way, but i would like to know the best way

thanks

Comment: Yes, there's LINQ syntax for this that the DB will convert into good SQL. Do you prefer the `select foo from Houses` LINQ syntax or `Houses.SelectMany()`?

Comment: but is it possible to do that on an object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using CTP5 I expect that this should work:

```
context.Windows.Local.SingleOrDefault(w => w.Id == idWindow);
```

Comment: Should i need to use Load before ?

Comment: Yes you need to load entities first or Local collection will be empty.